# using filtering in list of items using specific values contain in each item

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list for example

```
list = ["1234doy001.tif", "1233doy001.tif", "1111doy002.tif", "2222doy002.tif"]
```

I would like to filter the list that it will only give me list with values having doy001.

desired result:

```
filter = ["1234doy001.tif", "1233doy001.tif"]
```

I am trying

```
filter = [j for j in list if j == '*doy001*']
```

or

```
filter = [j for j in list if j == 'doy001']
```

but with no success. It just returns an empty list, like []

Please advise.

Thanks,
-Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With string `in` you can check if a string is contained in another

```
filter = [j for j in list if 'doy001' in j]
```

Answer (score 0):

`j == '*doy001*'` checks if `j` is equal to `*doy001*`

`j == 'doy001'` checks if `j` is equal to `doy001`

These approaches are both wrong.

Use the `in` operator;

```
filter = [j for j in list if 'doy001' in j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
filter =   [j for j in l if 'doy001' in j]
```

also

```
filter = [j for j in l if (j.find('doy001')!= -1)]
```

Hope this helps.